# Azure B2C password requirements for a password reset with a native client

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

From our native code, when attempting to change a user's password in a password reset flow, the password's complexity is not applied when we use an Admin account to change that password.

We are using the procedure as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword

In other words, when we attempt to change a password of a user using the user's identity token, the conditions for a password are applied.

But if we attempt to change that password by an Admin instead of the user's JWT, in a password reset situation, the minimum password requirements are not applied.

I suspect that maybe this has something to do with User Flows, but I am not certain.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Using admin to reset the user password with the AAD graph API, when the new password not complied with the complexity policy, it prompts an error.

[image]

Using admin to reset the user password with the Microsoft graph API, when the new password not complied with the complexity policy, it also prompts an error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. We will try with the Microsoft Graph API and see what that fixes/breaks.

Comment: We just tried using the MS Graph API and no change. It does not appear to apply the password rules.

Comment: @Justin, I update my answer here. If there is anything different with yours, please let me know, thanks.